# Canada Post AddressComplete Simple Setup showing setup dialog again

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use the canadapost's address auto-populate API per [Simple Setup here](https://www.canadapost-postescanada.ca/ac/support/setup-guides/#simple-setup).

It basically gives the user a CSS/JS snippet to add to the page, and once added, the page will show the following setup dialog.

[image]

Once you have mapped your own fields to Canada Post's field, and click Done, then the address look up will activate on your form.

However, I wanted to change the fields again, and was not able to get the setup dialog to show anymore.

Does anyone know how to reactivate the setup dialog?

Thanks